# Why does str(num) for binary number return only specific digits as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary

I have a number 000000000000001011 and I want to iterate over this. I used str(num) to iterate over it but it returns '11' as output string. Why does this happen?

Comment: How is that number stored? As a regular int?

Comment: Your question is confused, `str()` of `00001011` will give "1011" not "11".  Is this a typo?  Anyway, your number is not what you think it is.  If you wish to preserve those leading zeroes, the number needs to be kept in a string representation.

Comment: I do not want to preserve zeros. I want to count the number of  '1's for a given number, which in this case, is input as a binary number. And yes, I checked it a number of times, str(num) gives "11" instead of "1011" . Also, the binary number is given as an integer.

Comment: @Kingsley Actually `str(00001011)` will give `'521'` due to it being an octal number literal.

Comment: @blsing Python 3 doesn't seem to support octal literals, so this would actually give an error if it was in a context where octals were involved afaik. Unless that's just my version of Python.

Comment: 1011 is the binary representation of 11 as decimal. Probably the str() implicitly converts the binary number to a decimal first. Why not just declare the whole value as String literal initially, like 'xxxxxx'?!

Comment: @ErikReder - Yes, that's it.  The OP should state: `0b000000000000001011`.

Comment: @blhsing - Good point, this is a valid Python 2.x octal literal.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things at play here.

First, when the number is input, it is converted from string to integer format with the number-system specified (or that's my understanding from the question anyway):

```
number = int( user_input_str, 2 )  # user_input_str given in binary
```

But once it's stored internally, extraneous digits (for all intents and purposes) are now gone.

To iterate over the digits, you'd need to convert it back to a binary string:

```
number_str = '{0:b}'.format( number ).zfill( 18 )
```

or without leading zeros:

```
number_str = '{0:b}'.format( number )
```

This can then be iterated over easily:

```
for digit in number_str:
    # do whatever with each digit
```

Failing all that, just iterate over the user's input without the in-between conversion steps.